# I don't know how to reference a library that adds a function to jQuery (floatThead) in Angular2+

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the floatThead library which adds a function to jQuery. I import jQuery and successfully select the element I'd like to perform the function on. However, the `floatThead()` function is not found. I have tried adding the floatThead library to my angular-cli.json and also adding it via `<script>` on my template, to no avail. is there a way to accomplish this with `import`? The problem with that is I wouldn't know how to use the function (see below)

`import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as f from 'floatthead';`
...

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log($('#gridTable'));
    $('gridTable').floatThead();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import with es6 module syntax you can do

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'floatthead';
```

**Note:** By using this syntax, you do not need to include the scripts in your angular-cli.json. Webpack will import and bundle these as needed.

---

Alternatively, if you are loading jquery & floatthead in your scripts in angular-cli.json you can use the global `$` variable.

```
declare const $; // tells typescript that $ is available globally

export class Component {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log($('#gridTable'));
        $('gridTable').floatThead();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, same error message. I wonder if the issue is elsewhere because I thought this would work.

Comment: @NAMS Possibly, you'll have to import on each file you want to use it. I would also make sure your npm floatthead module is correctly installed.

Comment: @NAMS I did some additional testing. Are you still loading your scripts in angular-cli.json? (plus doing the import syntax) It seems to be conflicting when I try it. If so, remove the scripts from the json and retry

Comment: Okay, good call- that fixed it. I use bootstrap, so removing the jQuery reference from my angular-cli.json messes that up. Do you know another way I could satisfy bootstrap?

Comment: hmm, maybe import bootstrap within your ts as well. It probably depends on your use of bootstrap. Are you using the js functionality of bootstrap or just the css? Ultimately the option 2 I posted may better suite your needs

Comment: Thank you - i did not get that the angular-cli.json was adding scripts to the global scope until now, so I used the `declare const $` in my component to reference jQuery and it works perfect. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to a jQuery to scripts array in **.angular-cli.json**

Something like that:

```
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Comment: I do have jQuery referenced in my angular-cli.json and I added the floatThead library (which adds a function to jQuery), but when i try to use that function in my app it does not work.

`"scripts": [
 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
 "../node_modules/floatthead/dist/jquery.floatThead.min.js"
]`